# Adding ng-style using ForEach on Object

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have an array of objects in angular, what I want to do is iterate through the array and add a new property that I can call inside ng-style.  How can I add this style property like this?

```
  CommentService.GetComments(12535372).then(function () {
        $scope.comments = CommentService.data();
        angular.forEach($scope.comments, function (value, key) {
            $scope.comments.push('displayPercent:' +   'margin-left:'+ value.percent + '%');
        });

    });
```

My View:

```
<div ng-repeat="comment in comments">
     <div style="float: right;" ng-style="comment.displayPercent">
             {{ comment.comment }}
     </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming $scope.comments is an Array of Objects:

```
angular.forEach($scope.comments, function (value, key) {
  value.displayPercent = {'margin-left': value.percent + '%'};
});
```